# jQuery after() Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-after

```
for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {   
      $('#rows').after('<tr>
                           <td>'+ i + 1 + '</td>'
                           <td>'+rows[i][\'title\']+'</td>
                           <td>'+rows[i][\'startTime\']+' 
                        </tr>'); 
}
```

In the above jquery code, I would like to insert the table rows after the div with "rows" class in my html. However, I'm getting the error

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
```

may I know what is wrong and how can I solve it? thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot just put a new line character in the middle of the string in js, you must put a slash in the end of every line:

```
var a = 'foo \
bar \
baz';
```

alternatively you can concatenate several strings, one line each:

```
var a = 'foo ' +
        'bar ' +
        'baz';
```

Both examples are equivalent to:

```
var a = 'foo bar baz';
```

Addiitonally, `rows[i][\'title\']` is not a correct syntax either - you must not put slashes there.

Comment: in that case how can i escape the single quotes in rows[i]['title'] ?

Comment: @TommyLee you don't need to escape them - it's a proper JS

Answer (score 1):

Use concatenation well.

You should use:

```
for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {   
      $('#rows').after('<tr>\
                           <td>'+ i + 1 + '</td>\
                           <td>'+rows[i]["title"]+'</td>\
                           <td>'+rows[i]["startTime"]+' \
                        </tr>'); 
}
```

[**Take your Fiddle :)**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lqr95v89/2/)

Comment: "if you have Dom element or text in next line" --- what does this even mean?

Comment: instead of  `rows[i]["title"]` can i use `rows[i][\'title\']` ??

Comment: @TommyLee why did you put slashes there?

Comment: @TommyLee , yes but it will be escaping and LOT of messy for appending Big text with dom element. So better to use " " Double quotes in single and vice versa , Its clean method saves lots of headache.

Comment: because i already have double quotes outside this for loop. or how should i escape the single quotes in rows[i]['title']

Comment: "because i already have double quotes outside this for loop" --- what does it mean?

Comment: thanks to you too @jQuery.PHP.Magento.com! i removed the escape thingy in rows[i]['title'] and i used single quotes instead of double

Comment: @TommyLee NOW , I gave Proper JSFiddle too ! Still why downvotes ?? I dont get it !!!!

Comment: @zerkms NOW , I gave Proper JSFiddle too ! Still why downvotes ?? I dont get it !!!!

Comment: @jQuery.PHP.Magento.com why do you ask me actually? Btw, you still didn't answer what "if you have Dom element or text in next line" and how it is relevant with string operations.

Answer (score 1):

Try following code instead.

```
for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) 
{   
    $('#rows').after('<tr>' +
        '<td>'+ i + 1 + '</td>' +
        '<td>'+rows[i]['title']+'</td>' +
        '<td>'+rows[i]['startTime'] +
    '</tr>');
```

}